# Q promises and mongoose with connection.insert

Tags: mongoose, q

i have this piece of code:

```
var RidePaths = mongoose.model('ridepaths', ridePathSchema);
return q.nfcall(RidePaths.collection.insert, ridePaths);
```

and when I do execute it the promise does not get resolved (and the data does not get inserted);

If I do the plain promise approach it works:

```
var d = q.defer();
RidePaths.collection.insert(ridePaths, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    d.resolve(true);
});
return d.promise;
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s looks like

```
q.ninvoke(RidePaths.collection, 'insert', ridePaths);
```

works. Now I'm lost :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem, not really to do with Q, but to do with JavaScript in general. The problem is that when you pass functions to other functions, they lose their `this` context. You would have just as much of a problem if you did, e.g.

```
var func = RidePaths.collection.insert;
func(...); // does not work
```

The solution is to use `.bind`:

```
var func = RidePaths.collection.insert.bind(RidePaths.collection);
func(...); // works!
```

The same thing works in Q, where you're passing `RidePaths.collection.insert` as a function:

```
return q.nfcall(RidePaths.collection.insert.bind(RidePaths.collection), ridePaths);
```

This is of course verbose and ugly, so that's why we provided you with `ninvoke`, which as you noted works nicely:

```
return q.ninvoke(RidePaths.collection, 'insert', ridePaths);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this should be part of the Q introduction!

Comment: @nicco82 added as https://github.com/kriskowal/q/commit/ccaae9f4a88bb64c41609ec78922b587e56d2caf, see output at https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node